# Select and union same attributes from many tables using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, loops, union-all

I'm trying to write a more efficient PostgreSQL query that will UNION together the like attributes across numerous tables. Context is that the database has separate tables for results on different assessments, and I'm trying to look at the outcomes across all assessments. At the moment, for instance, I have one table that stores the name of all of the assessment tables:

```
| tables  |
|---------|
| table_a |
| table_b |
| table_c |
```

And I'm aggregating the outcomes together using this query (in reality, I'm aggregating across 25+ different tables):

```
SELECT person_id, subject_id, outcome
FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id, subject_id, outcome
FROM table_b
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id, subject_id, outcome
FROM table_c
```

Is there a PostgreSQL approach to essentially looping the same SELECT statement through multiple tables, and then UNION ALL results together (e.g. so I don't have to repeat the snippet above 25+ times)?

Answer (score 0):

You should write code that generates the statement for you. One thing you can do is to write a PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_them()
RETURNS TABLE (
   person_id bigint,
   subject_id bigint,
   outcome text
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   v_sql text := '';
   v_sep text := '';
   v_tab text;
BEGIN
   FOR v_tab IN
      SELECT tables FROM tab_of_tabs
   LOOP
      v_sql := v_sql || v_sep ||
         format(
            'SELECT person_id, subject_id, outcome FROM %I',
            v_tab
         );
      v_sep := ' UNION ALL ';
   END LOOP;

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_sql;
END;$$;
```